# Parse Html into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rss, hpple

i'm trying to read an RSS using `NSXMLParser` and that's ok.

This is the Xml that return from this RSS: http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/xml/rss/?id=roma

(for lazy people who don't will click the link, I leave an extract :) )

```
<item>
<title>Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles</title>
<link>
http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/
</link>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/
</guid>
<description>
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/" title="Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles" alt="DIO ESISTE E VIVE A BRUXELLES"" target="_blank">
<img src= "http://www.mymovies.it/filmclub/2015/05/113/mini.jpg" align="left" style="border:solid 1px #aeaeae; padding:3px; float:left; margin-right:3px; margin-top:3px;"/>
</a><b>Dio c'è, e vive a Bruxelles</b><br />
<![CDATA[...]]>
<![CDATA[...]]>
<![CDATA[...]]>
<![CDATA[...]]>
<![CDATA[...]]>
<![CDATA[...]]>
<span style="background-color:Green; padding:2px; color:White; font-size:9px; font-weight:bold;">Consigliato: Sì</span>
<br /> Regia di <a href="http://www.mymovies.it/biografia/?r=7593">Jaco Van Dormael</a>. 
Con <a href="http://www.mymovies.it/biografia/?a=199455">Pili Groyne</a>, 
<a href="http://www.mymovies.it/biografia/?a=70842">Benoît Poelvoorde</a>,   
<br /> Genere <a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/commedia/" title="Film commedia" target="_blank">Commedia</a>
 - Lussemburgo, Francia, Belgio, <a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/?anno=2015" title="Film 2015" target="_blank">2015</a>. 
Durata 113 minuti circa.<br/><br/>
<p style="text-align:justify; margin:0px; padding:0px;" >Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles con una moglie timorosa e una figlia ribelle. Il figlio, più celebre di lui, è fuggito molti anni prima per conoscere gli uomini più da vicino, morire per loro e lasciare testimonianza e testamento ai suoi dodici apostoli. Egoista e bisbetico, Dio governa il mondo da un personal computer facendo letteralmente il bello e il cattivo tempo sugli uomini. Ostacolato da Ea, decisa a seguire le orme del fratello e a fuggire il 'suo regno', la bambina si 'confronta' con JC (Jesus Christ) ed evade dall'oblò della lavatrice. Espulsa dentro una lavanderia self-service infila la via del mondo, recluta sei apostoli e si prepara a combattere l'ira di Dio, a cui ha manomesso il computer e di cui ha denunciato il sadismo, spedendo agli uomini via sms la data del loro decesso.</b><br /><br />
<b>A Roma: </b><br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/4912/" target="_blank">Cinema Mignon</a> (15:30 - - - 17:40 - - - 20:10 - - - 22:30) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/5255/" target="_blank">Cinema Eden Film Center</a> (15:00 - - - 17:30 - - - 19:40 - - - 22:10) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/20401/" target="_blank">Cinema Uci Cinemas Roma Est</a> (19:30 - - - 22:10) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/6882/" target="_blank">Cinema Uci Cinemas Parco Leonardo</a> (16:40 - - - 19:15 - - - 21:50) <br />
<div style="background-color:#D6D6D8; padding:3px;" ><a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/provincia/?f=84872" title="Orari e programmazione DIO ESISTE E VIVE A BRUXELLES" target="_blank">Orari e Programmazione</a> | <a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/" title="Recensione Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles" target="_blank">Recensione</a> | <a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/rassegnastampa/" title="Critica Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles" target="_blank">Critica</a> | <a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/trailer/" title="Trailer Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles" target="_blank">Trailer</a> | <a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2015/letoutnouveautestament/poster/" title="Locandina Dio esiste e vive a Bruxelles" target="_blank">Locandina</a></div><br /><br />
</description>
<category>film</category>
<category>recensioni</category>
<category>critica</category>
<category>trailer</category>
<category>locandine</category>
<category>cinema</category>
<category>di Roma</category>
</item>
```

**The goal is to take the information inside the element** `<description>` *especially the info about timetables of Cinema*:

```
A Roma: </b><br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/4912/" target="_blank">Cinema Mignon</a> (15:30 - - - 17:40 - - - 20:10 - - - 22:30) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/5255/" target="_blank">Cinema Eden Film Center</a>(15:00 - - - 17:30 - - - 19:40 - - - 22:10) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/20401/" target="_blank">Cinema Uci Cinemas Roma Est</a> (19:30 - - - 22:10) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/6882/" target="_blank">Cinema Uci Cinemas Parco Leonardo</a> (16:40 - - - 19:15 - - - 21:50) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/20642/" target="_blank">Cinema Uci Cinemas Porta di Roma</a> (21:50) <br /> - 
<a href= "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/5247/" target="_blank">Cinema Greenwich</a> (16:00 - - - 18:15 - - - 20:30 - - - 22:40)
```

**The output should be:**  Cinema Mignon (15:30 - - - 17:40 - - - 20:10 - - - 22:30)

I'm trying to use the library **Hpple** but the problem is here:

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

  //feeds is an NSMutableArray that has all information from Xml
  NSString *descr = [[feeds objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"description"];

  //this is not null
  NSData *data = [descr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  TFHpple *doc = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

  NSArray *elements = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@" "]; ????????
```

In `searchWithXPathQuery` what should I write? there aren't class or id or something that it allows me to identify what I need...

Thanks!

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? You can convert XML into a simple dictionary structure with other frameworks

Comment: @Wain I want to take the info inside the element <description> so i can reuse it.. in this case i want to take the info of where to see a movie .. but I don't know how

Comment: @Wain What other frameworks? thanks

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

Comment: @Wain that library not work in my case... I edited my question to better understand what exactly I need, can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same thing and I used [this](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) pod library.

Comment: ok man.. i wrote that i'm using this library but i don't know what write in searchWithXPathQuery ... can you show an example?

Comment: Try `[doc search:@"//a[@target='_blank']"];`

Comment: this search:// not work in my case.. I edited my question to better understand what exactly I need, can you help me? thanks

Comment: Well, I assume, that you have tried empty search for 'a' element. In case you didn't: `[doc search:@"//a"];` This would work for you with all links. You can filter them later, if there are any unwanted items.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just first parse the whole XML and then use regex or similar to parse the contents of the "description" tag?

For "http://www.mymovies.it/cinema/roma/4912/" target="_blank">Cinema Mignon (15:30 - - - 17:40 - - - 20:10 - - - 22:30) 
"

You will have something like (I'll just write the regex between "/", without worrying about which language you are using. Just to clarify, '/' is an escaped '/')

/(.*?)</a>(.*?)/

In regex group 1 you will find "Cinema Mignon", while in group 2 you will find " (15:30 - - - 17:40 - - - 20:10 - - - 22:30)".

THe regular exp. can be improved further to extract directly the time table.

Comment: Sorry, SO removed parts of the regex:

     /<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>(.*?)<br\s*\/>/

Comment: i'm trying to do some little changes and seems to works.. i'll let you know

Comment: I'm sorry, never used Objective-C, but i'm pretty sure it has built-in regex support.

Please also note that you will need to search FOR ALL matches of the regex in the <description> tag (The regex itself won't match all cinema events in once, but you'll need to loop over all matches..)